# Woocommerce Add only 1 product based on category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to write a script which allows the user to only add a single product from each category.

My method behind this is the following:-

- User clicks to add item
- If item is in basket with same quantity end script
- If the quantity is different update with new quantity
- If product is not in basket, check to see if other items are in the basket belonging to the same category
- If items exist remove items belonging to the same category name
- Add new item

Is something like this possible?

I'm not to sure where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know I can trigger a jQuery event using the following tag:-

```
jQuery('button').on('added_to_cart',function() {
    jQuery.post("?wc-ajax=add_to_cart",
    {
        product_id: jQuery(this).attr('data-product_id'),
        quantity: jQuery(this).attr('data-quantity'),
    },
    function(data,status){
    });
});
```

But this is where I get stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise you to do your validation on the backend via the [`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/76b32c9aa52ebac70fe5a60a8d56351218760471/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L624) filter

Comment: @helgatheviking I have attempted to use this but it add the product to the cart and then pushes me to the product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to acheive what I wanted:-

```
<?php

if ( ! is_admin() ) add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_product_to_cart', 1 );
function add_product_to_cart() {

    global $woocommerce;

    // Getting posted product information
    $post_product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $post_product_qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $post_product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post_product_id , 'product_cat' );
    $post_product_cat = $post_product_cats[0]->name;

    // Getting cart items
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) {

        // Getting cart product information
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        $_product_id = $_product->ID;
        $_product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $_product_id , 'product_cat' );
        $_product_cat = $_product_cats[0]->name;
        $_product_qty = $values['quantity'];
        $prod_unique_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $_product_id );

        // Check if product categories are the same
        if($post_product_cat == $_product_cat){
            // Check if the product ID's are the same
            if($post_product_id == $_product_id){
                // Check if quantities are different
                if($post_product_qty != $_product_qty){
                    // Update quantities if they are different
                    WC()->cart->set_quantity($prod_unique_id, $post_product_qty);
                }
            } else {
                // Remove items that are in the same category
                unset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[$prod_unique_id] );
            }
        }

    } 

}
```